# Vite is not compiling my dynamic imports anymore

Tags: reactjs, vite

I had this code in my React project built with Vite:

```
const modules = ['SomeModule', 'SomeAnotherModule', 'YetAnotherModule'];
modules.forEach(module => {
    import(`../${module}/Index.jsx`).then(importResult => {
        // code to work with importResult
    });
});
```

This dynamic import then would be seen in the `assets` when I would run `npm run build`:

```
✓ 3161 modules transformed.
rendering chunks...
computing gzip size...
dist/index.html                      3.24 kB
dist/assets/Logo-fb9b9963.svg        3.29 kB
dist/assets/Brand-811e6eb1.svg       5.32 kB
dist/assets/index-030aeab6.css      44.03 kB │ gzip:   7.26 kB
dist/assets/Index-fcadcbd5.js      0.06 kB │ gzip:   0.07 kB
dist/assets/Index-e915026c.js      0.08 kB │ gzip:   0.09 kB
dist/assets/Index-35cea10d.js      0.11 kB │ gzip:   0.12 kB
dist/assets/Index-1c8063b3.js      0.13 kB │ gzip:   0.12 kB
dist/assets/Index-03012268.js      0.21 kB │ gzip:   0.15 kB
dist/assets/Index-e1ae11fa.js      0.23 kB │ gzip:   0.17 kB
dist/assets/Index-4e9568e8.js      0.27 kB │ gzip:   0.18 kB
dist/assets/Index-d1dcf9fe.js      0.67 kB │ gzip:   0.39 kB
dist/assets/Index-0aebb39d.js      0.71 kB │ gzip:   0.44 kB
dist/assets/Index-4eae8923.js      0.84 kB │ gzip:   0.55 kB
dist/assets/Index-1eb134f4.js      1.16 kB │ gzip:   0.65 kB
dist/assets/Index-33708fb7.js      1.30 kB │ gzip:   0.68 kB
dist/assets/Index-891c24a0.js      1.59 kB │ gzip:   0.61 kB
dist/assets/Index-9d2db0da.js      1.60 kB │ gzip:   0.74 kB
dist/assets/Index-afe5f6fa.js      1.62 kB │ gzip:   0.80 kB
dist/assets/index-d90fe5d4.js    1,485.69 kB │ gzip: 454.53 kB
```

However, after I upgraded my packages, I don't see that anymore. All I see is this:

```
vite v4.2.1 building for production...
transforming...
✓ 3169 modules transformed.
rendering chunks...
computing gzip size...
dist/index.html                   3.24 kB
dist/assets/index-41dae4cc.css   44.02 kB │ gzip:   7.33 kB
dist/assets/index-82d11f17.js   855.45 kB │ gzip: 251.83 kB
```

As you can see, all those dynamic imports are not considered/compiled. And from the size of the main JS file I can see that nothing from my dynamic components are actually compiled.

What should I do?